# how to solve an issue using segmentation-models library

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, semantic-segmentation

I installed segmentation-models library using pip as the provided instruction

[enter link description here](https://segmentation-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)

. this is what I got after importing it:

```
from segmentation_models import Unet
model = Unet()
```

This is the error I got:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-4835d2c1eebe> in <module>
      3 from segmentation_models import Unet
      4 
----> 5 model = Unet()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\segmentation_models\__init__.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     32         kwargs['models'] = _KERAS_MODELS
     33         kwargs['utils'] = _KERAS_UTILS
---> 34         return func(*args, **kwargs)
     35 
     36     return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\segmentation_models\models\unet.py in Unet(backbone_name, input_shape, classes, activation, weights, encoder_weights, encoder_freeze, encoder_features, decoder_block_type, decoder_filters, decoder_use_batchnorm, **kwargs)
    224         weights=encoder_weights,
    225         include_top=False,
--> 226         **kwargs,
    227     )
    228 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\segmentation_models\backbones\backbones_factory.py in get_backbone(self, name, *args, **kwargs)
    101     def get_backbone(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
    102         model_fn, _ = self.get(name)
--> 103         model = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    104         return model
    105 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\classification_models\models_factory.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     76             modules_kwargs = self.get_kwargs()
     77             new_kwargs = dict(list(kwargs.items()) + list(modules_kwargs.items()))
---> 78             return func(*args, **new_kwargs)
     79 
     80         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_applications\vgg16.py in VGG16(include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape, pooling, classes, **kwargs)
    100 
    101     if input_tensor is None:
--> 102         img_input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    103     else:
    104         if not backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py in Input(shape, batch_shape, name, dtype, sparse, tensor)
    176                              name=name, dtype=dtype,
    177                              sparse=sparse,
--> 178                              input_tensor=tensor)
    179     # Return tensor including _keras_shape and _keras_history.
    180     # Note that in this case train_output and test_output are the same pointer.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py in __init__(self, input_shape, batch_size, batch_input_shape, dtype, input_tensor, sparse, name)
     37         if not name:
     38             prefix = 'input'
---> 39             name = prefix + '_' + str(K.get_uid(prefix))
     40         super(InputLayer, self).__init__(dtype=dtype, name=name)
     41 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in get_uid(prefix)
     72     """
     73     global _GRAPH_UID_DICTS
---> 74     graph = tf.get_default_graph()
     75     if graph not in _GRAPH_UID_DICTS:
     76         _GRAPH_UID_DICTS[graph] = defaultdict(int)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

I would be appreciated if someone can help me with how to fix it. I simply copy the code from the instruction, and all I found on the net was just the same. Should it be something wrong with installation?

Comment: What version of tensorflow do you have installed?

Comment: @DMolony, tf.__version__ is '2.0.0-beta1'

Answer (score 0):

tf.get_default_graph() is no longer available in tensorflow2.x. If you downgrade to tensorflow 1.15 this error should be resolved.

Comment: I need TensorFlow version 2 for other codes. can't I resolve it without this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new environment and install these and it will work.

```
!pip install keras-segmentation
!pip install tensorflow==1.14
!pip install keras==2.2.4
!pip install -U segmentation-models==0.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved by adding

```
tf.keras.backend.set_image_data_format('channels_last')
```

before importing unet. Also, do not import keras, just use tensorflow.